# Look Up Table Assembly Compile Time

Tags: assembly, x86, lookup-tables

How can I write a look up table in assembly x86 that will be calculated at compile time? I do not want to copy all values hardcoded into a file, but I couldn't find another way.

Comment: Write a program that generates the table and have it generate an assembly file.  Integrate running this program into your build process.

Comment: You can also consult online-tables at https://www.sandpile.org/ or http://ref.x86asm.net/

Comment: Which assembler are you using? and can you provide more information on the specific lookup you need?

Comment: Put the table in the data section (as global data or as global rodata), and initialize it with the constant values you want, using the data size you want.  Give it a label, and use that label to reference it from code.